# Android Lollipop Switch: textOn is same color as switch icon and doesn't show

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am using a switch in the Options Menu on Android Lollipop 5.0 Android Studio.  The Switch On looks like this:
[Switch On](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW3iR.png)
The Switch Off looks like this:
[Switch Off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ6ou.png)
   - You can't see the "O" - it is presumably white text on the white Off switch.  How can I change the color of the text (or at least the switch color)?
  Here is my xml:

```
<Switch  android:id="@+id/switchRackOverflowToggle"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:textOn="O"
 android:textOff="R"
 android:showText="true"
 android:checked="false"/>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
</selector>
```

and

```
switchButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.button_text_color));
```

Comment: Ivan, thanks for responding!  I am a bit unsure of what to do with the code that you presented.  After looking up the Selector it seems to allow the customization of textboxes, buttons, and presumably also the switch.  But I'm not sure how the .xml file and the switchbutton.setTextColor command get tied together.  Would you mind elaborating a bit more on your solution?  I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around further I found an easy way to change the colors of the switch itself: http://www.materialdoc.com/switch/

```
<style name="MySwitch" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">  
<!-- active thumb & track color (30% transparency) -->
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/indigo</item>

<!-- inactive thumb color -->
<item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/pink</item>

<!-- inactive track color (30% transparency) -->
<item name="android:colorForeground">@color/grey</item>
</style>
```

Then for the switch use:

```
 android:theme="@style/MySwitch"
```

Now I can see my Text overlay more clearly.